# Propositional Logic with rules of inference problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, equivalence-relations

$$
\begin{array}{l}
1.\>\>\>\> (r ∧ ¬s) ∨ (q ∧ ¬s)\\
2.\>\>\>\> ¬s → ((p ∧ r) → u)\\
3.\>\>\>\> u → (s ∧ ¬t)\\
\dfrac{\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}{\text{Prove from the previous arguments. }\quad p → q}
\end{array}
$$

Hey guys, I am really lost, so far I have a few arguments but not sure if they're correct. Can you please give some arguments to get this solved or a game plan using Inference laws and equivalences. Inferences: Modus Ponens, Tollens, Hypothetical, Disjunctive, Resolution, Conjunction, Simplification, Addition.

This is what I have so far....
4. (r ∨ q) ∧ ¬s Distributive of 1
5. ¬s Simplification of 1
6. (p ∧ r) → u Modus Ponens of 2
7. ¬u Modus Tollens of 3
8. ¬(p ∧ r) Modus tollens
9. p → ¬r DeMorgans and Implication Definition\
10. (r ∨ q) Simplification
11. ( ¬r → q) Implication
12. p → q Hypothetical

Are these steps valid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rules of Inference....From the following premises, conclude that p → q.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676025/rules-of-inference-from-the-following-premises-conclude-that-p-q)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give a summary "sketch" of one proof approach.

I'd suggest you start from the first premise:

First check what follows from $r\land \lnot s$ and then what follows when $q \land \lnot s$. (At least one of these must be true. Why?)

From each of the above, we can use conjunction elimination (or simplification) to obtain $\lnot s$. And so, we can use disjunction elimination to conclude $\lnot s$.

From $\lnot s$ and premise $(2)$, we can derive (infer), by modus ponens, $(p\land r)\rightarrow u$.

From $(p \land r) \rightarrow u$ together with premise $(3)$, we get $(p\land r) \rightarrow (s \land \lnot t)$

Now, we already derived $\lnot s.$ This means $\lnot s \lor t$ is true. Why?

But $\lnot s \lor t \equiv \lnot (s \land \lnot t).$

From $\lnot (s \land \lnot t),$ together with our derived $(p\land r )\rightarrow (s\land \lnot t)$, by modus ponens, we get $\not(p \land r)$

This means that either $\lnot p$, or $\lnot r$ is true.

If $\lnot p$ is true, we can build from this (addition) to get $\lnot p \lor q \equiv p\rightarrow q$, as desired.

If $\lnot r$ is true, then $r\land \lnot s$ is false (first alternative from premise $(1)$. Then it must follow that $q\land \lnot s$ is true. So it follows that $q$ is true (simplification). And given $q$, we have $\lnot p \lor q$ (addition), which is equivalent to $p \rightarrow q$, as desired.

Therefore, from $\lnot (p \land r)\equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot r$ we can conclude $(q\rightarrow q)$.

I'll leave this to you to write formally (including keeping proper track of temporary assumptions), with proper justifications.

Comment: I just saw your edit. I think you're thinking along the right lines.

Comment: Thank you, can you please clarify the following if you have a chance: Now, we already derived ¬s. This means ¬s∨t is true. Why?

But ¬s∨t≡¬(s∧¬t).

Comment: Becuase if $\lnot s$ is true, $\lnot s \lor$ ... "something else" is certainly true (truth-table for $\lor$); so, we use as "something else" $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

---

- 1:    **(r∧¬s)∨(q∧¬s)**      *Premise*
- 2:    **¬s→((p∧r)→u)**       *Premise*
- 3:    **u→(s∧¬t)**           *Premise*
- 4:    **(r∨q)∧ ¬s**          *Distribution 1*
- 5:    **¬s**                 *Simplification 4*
- 6:    **(p∧r)→u**            *Modus Ponens 2, 5*
- 7:    **¬s∨t**               *Addition 5*
- 8:    **¬(s∧¬t)**            *DeMorgan 7*
- 9:    **¬u**                 *Modus Tollens 3, 8*
- 10:   **¬(p∧r)**             *Modus Tollens 6, 9*
- 11:   **¬p∨¬r**              *DeMorgan 10*
- 12:   **p→¬r**               *Material implication 11*
- 13:   **r∨q**                *Simplification 4*
- 14:   **¬r→q**               *Material implication 13*
- 15:   **p→q**                *Hypothetical silogism 12, 14*